# RxJS Observable methods on assigned variable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Why is it that you have to chain observable instance methods for them to work. If you assign an observable to a variable, then apply a new observable method, the new method will not be called.

For example, this works:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .map(function (x) {
        return x;
    })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log("Finally");
  });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);   
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');   
    });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.2.28/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

But this doesn't call the finally() method:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .map(function (x) {
        return x;
    });

// This is never called
source.finally(function() {
  console.log("Finally");
});

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);   
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');   
    });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.2.28/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Observable methods do not add an operation to the original observable and then return the original observable to be passed down the line. They actually return a new observable.

The second example above does not work because source.finally() does not append the finally() method to the source observable. Instead it returns a new observable which will call the finally() method. So in the example, the source variable has no knowledge that source.finally() was called. To make example two work, we need the following:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .map(function (x) {
        return x;
    });

source = source.finally(function() {
  console.log("Finally");
});

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);   
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');   
    });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.2.28/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```